# How can I check the dimensions of a selection/object in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5

Want to check the current dimensions of an object/selection in pixels. How do I do this? Illustrator CS5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your ruler units to pixels, select the objects and check the values in your control bar or transform or info panel.